# PHP Loop through JSON String from POST request

Tags: php, arrays, json, post

How do l loop through this JSON String in PHP and get all the URLS?

```
{
    "item": "1.2.840.113619.2.55.1.1762903756.1942.1319006898.442",
    "title": [{
            "images": "{'1.2.840.113619.2.55.1.1762903756.1942.1319006898.446.1':{'url': 'https:www.example11.com', 'observationTime': 'None'}}"
        },
        {
            "images": "{'1.2.840.113619.2.55.1.1762903756.1942.1319006898.446.1':{'url': 'https:www.example33.com', 'observationTime': 'None'}, '1.2.840.113619.2.55.1.1762903756.1942.1319006898.446.55':{'url': 'https:www.example44.com', 'observationTime': 'None'}, '1.2.840.113619.2.55.1.1762903756.1942.1319006898.446.99':{'url': 'https:www.example55.com', 'observationTime': 'None'}}"
        },
        {
            "images": "{'1.2.840.113619.2.55.1.1762903756.1942.1319006898.446.1':{'url': 'https:www.example66.com', 'observationTime': 'None'}}"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Tried the following and it didn't work**

```
$data=json_decode ($stringBody,TRUE);
for($i=0; $i<count($data['title']); $i++) {
  $data=$data['title'];

   foreach($data as $obj){
     $imagesData =$obj['images'];

      foreach($imagesData as $value){
          print "<p>" . $value->url  . "</p>";
      }

   }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should use a different name for the variable in the loop; don't overwrite `$data`. Also note that you don't need a loop in a loop, 1 should do it.

Comment: as you have passed true in json decode it will convert to recursive multi dimensional array .. so use `$value['url']` instead of `$value->url`

Comment: @jeroen Thanks, tried your suggestion and it didn't work. foreach($imagesData as $value){
          print "<p>" . $value->url  . "</p>";
      } is never called

Answer (score 1):

```
$array_data = json_decode($json_data, true)["title"];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array_data); $i++) {
    $image = $array_data[$i]['images'];
    //As the content in image is not  a valid json
    // Convert to valid json
    $image_valid_json = str_replace("'", "\"", $image);
    //change to array
    $image_data = json_decode($image_valid_json, true);
    //get the long key
    $key = array_keys($image_data);
    // Changes as per your question
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($key); $j++) {
        $url = $image_data[$key[$j]]['url'];
        echo $url . "\n";
    }
}
```

The data in the image of your json is just a string and that is not a valid json verified at jsonlint. So before using it you need to convert to json and then only you can decode to array and access the   url.

Comment: This looks promising. I get some of the URLS  and not all.  I think this line     $url = $image_data[$key[0]]['awsurl']; only display first URL of every Images

Comment: @ErnestAppiah All of your urls are same, change it you will se all urls are being printed

Answer (score 0):

Try this PHP code

```
$data=json_decode ($stringBody,TRUE);
foreach($data['title'] as $url){
   $string = "[" . str_replace("'", '"', $url['images']) . "]";
   $json = json_decode($string,true);
   foreach($json[0] as $key => $val){
     print_r($json[0][$key]['url']);
     echo "<br/>";
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$data=json_decode ($stringBody,TRUE);
for($i=0; $i<count($data['title']); $i++) {
  $data=$data['title'];

   foreach($data as $obj){
     $imagesData =$obj['images'];

      foreach($imagesData as $value){
          print "<p>" . $value['url']  . "</p>";
      }

   }
}
```

Comment: Look more closely at the code, specifically at `$data=$data['title'];`

Comment: Thanks, however, the last innder for loop is never called. It doesn't work

Comment: used foreach instead of for